# Equation differential non linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a question how can I get the exact solution of the following non-linear problem?
$$u''+uu'-u=e^{2x} , \ \ u(0)=1, u(1)=e.$$

Try the following to solve the homogeneous equation:
Putting $ v=u' \rightarrow  u''=v\frac{dv}{du}$ by separating variables $-v-\ln|1-v|=\frac{u^2}{2}+c_1$

so $v=1+c_2 e^{-v-\frac{u^2}{2}+c_1} \rightarrow u'= 1+c_2 e^{-u'-\frac{u^2}{2}+c_1}$

and from here I don't know how to find $u(x)$ ???

Comment: Generally speaking solving the homogeneous equation first isn't all that useful for nonlinear ODEs. For this equation there is actually an extremely simple solution.

Comment: Try $ u(x) = e^x$

Comment: Ok,the answer is: $e^{x}$  ,  but the thing is to arrive at that answer analytically

Comment: What would be another way to solve it?